# Difference between Google Map Distance and Directions API

Tags: android, google-maps

Google provides APIs for 1. Distance Matrix and 2. Direction service

I tried to search about difference between 1 and 2

> My task is "When user moves from Source **S** to Destination **D**
>   using some path. We need to show the **actual path user has traversed
>   on Google Map**"

What is best way to accomplish it ?

Using 1. Distance Matrix APIs or 2. Direction service

Comment: I think second one 'Direction service' is right choice for your requirement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Google Maps API picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker)

You use Directions service for getting directions from origin to destination location using various forms of transport: walking, driving, cycling, public transit. Get a route from point A to point B.

For Distance Matrix it calculate the travel distance and travel time for multiple origins and destinations, optionally specifying various forms of transport: walking, driving, cycling.

For your case, I will suggest Directions service since you don't need travel time.

Answer (score 5):

I got answer to my question.

Google Maps V2 provides 2 sets of APIs for developers

**1. Distance Matrix APIs** : this is useful for computing **distance**(walking/travelling via bycycle,bus), **cost of travel**, **time of travel**

But this is not useful for this scenario.

**2. Direction Service :** this is useful for this scenario.

Through direction service, we can get the path of User on Google Map in Real Time

> If we get the path through Distance Matrix, then Google Map returns
>   the **shortest established path** between **S** Source and **D**
>   Destination, this is not desirable in this scenario. User may not use
>   shortest path due to some trafic, personal reasons and Diatance Matrix
>   API output fails here.

So, I should use **Direction Service** API which give me real time Output for User location on Google Map

Thank you for your replies