# Is it possible to get the longitude, latitude and timestamp from google maps API for the places travelled in the past?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I was thinking of building an app for a hackathon, in which I need to know if it is possible to get the location coordinates and the timestamp of those coordinates.

For example say, X was at A in time p and at B in time q, now can I get these parameters from the Google Maps API, which will have to be fetched from its history?
[This is a place where one can check there location history](https://maps.google.co.in/locationhistory) 
What I want to know is, is it possible through the API?

As you would have guessed I am a complete noob in android, so any help is valuable. :) Thanks in advance.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have searched through Google and other sources, Google do not provide API which results us travel path or places in recent history time.

> But...
>
> Google has provided APIs set through which we can implement this task
>   on our own.  They are **Distance Matrix APIs** and **Direction service APIs**

For achieveing this task, Direction service APIs are good way to implement

You can check my question : [Difference between Google Map Distance and Directions API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28956350/1994950)

I have found good tutorials which i am giving you :

1. [Showing Current location on Google Map Android](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/)
2. [Driving Location from our location to any destination](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/)

I am also trying to implement this task using above two tutorials.